# How to make http calls from android

Tags: java, android

Hi I want to use this code in thread , How I can do this ??
this code use for read rss feed in android.

```
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}
```

Comment: In thread? Maybe there is a class named AsyncTask to do the jobs like this.

Comment: I'm guessing you need http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask on Network Operations. This is an example:

```
private class YourTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // result is your xml. You can use it here.
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {}
}
```

You can call this thread with `new YourTask().execute((Void)null);`

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In class field place define a handler and then place your code like below example in it;

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
... 

public void MyOnClick(View v){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {         
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Rubnable()){
                {your code}
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

the best way is use AsyncTask ...